# Bubble Sort ending in an infinite loop

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I created a program for bubble sort. It ends up in an infinite loop.
I have included comments at places so that the code is easily understandable.
Any suggestions on how to make the code smaller are welcome.

I was debugging the program and found this -

When stdin was "ccbbaa" and after some recursions when finally input(aabbcc) and temp(aabbcc) were same, then after the condition of strcmp() was executed, the value of 'temp' was  changed to "baabcc".

1. Any reasons as to why this happened? — This is the reason for the infinite loop.
2. Does a character array have a '\0' at the end (while copying input to temp)?

I solved the problem by using a for loop instead of strcmp(). Investigating why strcmp() doesn't work currently.

Updated code is available - http://ideone.com/4Bdblh ( solved )

#### Buggy code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void sort(char* input)
{
    const int length = strlen(input);
    int j = length -1;
    char temp[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        temp[i]= *(input+i);
    }

    while(j)
    {
        if((int)*(input+1) < (int)*(input))
        {
            char temp1;
            temp1 = *(input);
            *input = *(input + 1);
            *(input + 1) = temp1;
        }
        input++;
        j--;
    }
        input = input - length +1;
        while(strcmp(temp,input))
        {
        sort(input);
        }
}
int main()
{
    char* input = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",input);
    sort(input);
    printf("%s",input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You should read [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: thanks, currently reading it. will remember for future postings.

Comment: 1) write a few printf before each loop, look 1st in which loop it got stuck. 2) examine the loop and try to follow the logic, probably the condition is simply not met.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this... watch CS50's video about the pseudocode of bubble sort again and try to do it with simple char arrays first. No pointer arithmetic or recursion etc. When you finally succeed in making it work with arrays and iteration... then you try recursion, pointer arithmetic etc

Comment: can strcmp() by any chance change a string? cause it does while i compare "aabbcc"- temp  with "aabbcc"- input TO "baabcc - temp and "aabbcc" - input -----  found that while debugging

Comment: does a character array have a '\0' at the end ?( while copying input to temp )

Comment: @PrakharSharma, no `strcmp()` never changes either input string.  Indeed, the argument string contents are declared `const`.

Comment: ok thanks , ialso wanted to ask if there is a way to declare a constant string using const char* array? i tried that but the addresses linked to them changed & so the values changed. i also tried const, const inside

Comment: @PrakharSharma a character array does not automatically behave as if there is a `\0` in it anywhere (except an array corresponding to a string literal).  If you want one, then it's up to you to make sure there is one.  On the other hand, what is *beyond* the end of an array is **undefined**.  Your program exhibits undefined behavior if it ever tries to access outside the bounds of an array, via an expression based on that array.

Comment: @PrakharSharma, I suggest that you forget about `const` for now.  It doesn't mean quite what you think it means, and unless you understand it well, it will not be helpful to you.  I furthermore suggest that you take yLaguardia's advice to simplify.  You're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be, and it is confusing you.  You don't need recursion, or pointer arithmetic, nor even `strlen()` or `strcmp()`.  And though it's probably not harming you, you don't need `malloc()`, either.

Comment: allright, i had just learnt pointers and functions a week ago and was thinking about using them all haha

Comment: thanks for the head-up , appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Answer using arrays and for loops-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX 1000

void sort(char input[])
{
    const int length = strlen(input);
    int j = length -1;
    char temp[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        temp[i]= input[i];
    }
    int l=0;
    while(j)
    {

        if(input[l+1] < input[l])
        {
            char temp1;
            temp1 = input[l];
            input[l] = input[l+1];
            input[l+1] = temp1;
        }
        l++;
        j--;
    }
        for(int k=0; k<length; k++)
        {
            if(temp[k]!=input[k])
            {
                sort(input);
            }
        }       
}
int main()
{
    char input[MAX];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",input);
    sort(input);
    printf("%s",input);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C a string is just a char array ending in 0.

All string functions assume char arrays end with zero.

strcpy copies the string including the 0 delimiter at the end. Therefore, destination must have enough space for the string plus the zero.

strlen returns the length of the string, so the destination must be at least strlen (input)+1 long.

If you copy the string in a loop, then you mustn't forget to add the ending zero.

What I don't really get is why to make it recursive and doing a string comparison to detect completion. You can just implement two nested loops from 0 to length - 2. It's warranted it'll be sorted in the end.

If you want to make it adaptive, just store the last position you swapped. You needn't go further the next loop.

Answer (score 0):

> When stdin was "ccbbaa" and after some recursions when finally input(aabbcc) and temp(aabbcc) were same, then after the condition of strcmp() was executed, the value of 'temp' was  changed to "baabcc".
>
> 1. Any reasons as to why this happened? — This is the reason for the infinite loop.

It just looked like *the value of 'temp' was  changed to "baabcc"* because the function returned to the previous recursion level where the local `temp` had the same value as before. The main *reason for the infinite loop* is that due to the `while(strcmp(temp,input))` the old, unsorted `temp` is compared again and again.

> 2. Does a character array have a '\0' at the end (while copying input to temp)?

The `temp` array in the buggy code hasn't; you could have written

```
    char temp[length+1];
    strcpy(temp, input);
```

or just used `strncmp()` rather than `strcmp()`.

So, for the program to work it is sufficient to change

```
        while(strcmp(temp,input))
```

to

```
        if (strncmp(temp, input, length))
```